# Sailsjs Waterlock - Set up multiple auth methods

Tags: authentication, sails.js, waterlock

I have been learning how to use SailsJS most effectively, which includes using authentication. After the nightmare that `sails-auth` gave me, I decided to use `Waterlock`.

I have a default setup with `Waterlock`. I am trying to use multiple auth strategies ([waterlock-local-auth](https://github.com/waterlock/waterlock-local-auth) + [waterlock-google-auth](https://github.com/waterlock/waterlock-google-auth)).

Whenever I POST credentials to the register page, I am presented with

`HTTP 400: you must specify a type parameter.`

After reading the code, I notice I must submit an `authentication type` string with my form submit. So I add `<input type="hidden" name="type" value="waterlock-local-auth"/>` to the form. However, now I am presented with this:

`HTTP 400: unknown/invalid authentication type`

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to encode the `type` string in the form data this way:

- Your auth package name is `waterlock-x-auth`
- The `value` on the input tag should be `x`

The input tag (if using local, for example) would look like this:

`<input type="hidden" name="type" value="local"/>`